# Height issue with display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

I am having height issue with slider pager(image attached). i.e display:table-cell is not taking the height.

Here is the screenshot of the ul li block:

[image: Ul li block which is pager]

HTML part is below

```
<ul class="rslides_tabs rslides1_tabs">
<li class="rslides1_s1"><a class="rslides1_s1" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
<li class="rslides1_s2"><a class="rslides1_s2" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
<li class="rslides1_s3"><a class="rslides1_s3" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
<li class="rslides1_s4 rslides_here"><a class="rslides1_s4" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS part below:

```
.rslides_tabs {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 71.5%;
display: table;
table-layout: fixed; /* the magic dust that ensures equal width */
}

.rslides_tabs li {
 display: table-cell;
margin-right: 1px;
}

.rslides_tabs li a{
display:block
}
```

I need equal spaces for each li, so it acts as pager plus progress bar.

Issue is with height of the li which is shown as a horizontal block in image(as you click on bar, red mark moves-simple pager of a slider). I am not able to reduce the height, can someone please help me on this?

I want pager should look like below image:

[image: Final result should be]

Comment: Can you please provide a demo in JSFiddle or CodePen? Bacause your code's result is not the same as in your first image.

Comment: Try: `.rslides_tabs li{ vertical-align:top; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I believe the elements of your code are having their height determined by the height of the font itself.  In this way, any CSS height is overridden by the font-size as it requires the text (even if it is only a space) to fit inside.

If you reduce the font-size, you could reduce the height of the bar.

Something like:

`.rslides_tabs li { font-size:0.8em; }`

should shrink the height of your bar.